# How does git cherry-pick compute the patch?

Tags: git, cherry-pick, git-cherry-pick

I understand how git cherry-pick works at a high level: It takes the changes introduced in one commit and applies them to another.

However, I’m trying to gain a better understanding of how git actually achieves this under the hood.

Suppose you run the following:

```
$ git checkout main
$ git cherry-pick source-commit
```

My understanding is that since a commit is a snapshot, not a set of changes, that cherry-pick must first be computing some sort of diff, and then applying that patch/diff to the current branch (`main`). Is this patch just the diff of `source-commit` with its parent? Is the merge base of `source-commit` and `main` involved at all?

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, doing a `git cherry-pick HASH` with a single commit is more or less equivalent to:

1. `git show --patch HASH > temp.diff`
2. `git apply temp.diff`

In turn, step 1 above computes the difference between the given commit and its single parent.

(You can cherry-pick a merge, but you have to specify what parent to compare against, with option `-m parent-number`.)

About the merge base, AFAIK the merge base of HASH and `main` is not involved at all. Note that in case of conflicts, if you have configured the `diff3` conflict style, the middle hunk (which for merges is the merge base) is just the parent of the cherry.

Comment: More precisely, it's like using `git am --3way` on the patch, since cherry-pick will both do a merge if needed and make a new commit. Internally, `git cherry-pick` uses the merge machinery (using `git merge-recursive` by default) with the merge base simply forced to be the parent, or with `-m`, the selected parent, of the commit being cherry-picked.